# Assert that a method was called with one argument out of several

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm mocking out a call to `requests.post` using the `Mock` library:

```
requests.post = Mock()
```

The the call involves multiple arguments: the URL, a payload, some auth stuff, etc. I want to assert that `requests.post` is called with a particular URL, but I don't care about the other arguments. When I try this:

```
requests.post.assert_called_with(requests_arguments)
```

the test fails, as it expects it to be called with only that argument.

Is there any way to check if a single argument is used somewhere in the function call without having to pass in the other arguments?

Or, even better, is there a way to assert a specific URL and then abstract data types for the other arguments (i.e., data should be a dictionary, auth should be an instance of HTTPBasicAuth, etc.)?

Comment: No relation to the questions, but if you are mocking REST calls, the `requests-mock` module might also be interesting.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As far as I know `Mock` doesn't provide a way to achieve what you want via `assert_called_with`. You could access the [`call_args`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) and [`call_args_list`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) members and perform the assertions manually.

However the is a simple (and dirty) way of achieving *almost* what you want. You have to implement a class whose `__eq__` method always returns `True`:

```
def Any(cls):
    class Any(cls):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return True
    return Any()
```

Using it as:

```
In [14]: caller = mock.Mock(return_value=None)


In [15]: caller(1,2,3, arg=True)

In [16]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(int), Any(int), arg=True)

In [17]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(int), Any(int), arg=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c604faa06bd0> in <module>()
----> 1 caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(int), Any(int), arg=False)

/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/mock.py in assert_called_with(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs)
    724         if self.call_args != (args, kwargs):
    725             msg = self._format_mock_failure_message(args, kwargs)
--> 726             raise AssertionError(msg)
    727 
    728 

AssertionError: Expected call: mock(0, 0, 0, arg=False)
Actual call: mock(1, 2, 3, arg=True)
```

As you can see it only checks for the `arg`. You have to create subclasses of `int`, otherwise the comparisons wont work<sup>1</sup>. However you still have to provide all the arguments. If you have many arguments you might shorten your code using tuple-unpacking:

```
In [18]: caller(1,2,3, arg=True)

In [19]: caller.assert_called_with(*[Any(int)]*3, arg=True)
```

Except for this I cannot think of a way to avoid passing all parameters to `assert_called_with` and work it as you intend.

---

The above solution can be extended to check for types of other arguments. For example:

```
In [21]: def Any(cls):
    ...:     class Any(cls):
    ...:         def __eq__(self, other):
    ...:             return isinstance(other, cls)
    ...:     return Any()

In [22]: caller(1, 2.0, "string", {1:1}, [1,2,3])

In [23]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(float), Any(str), Any(dict), Any(list))

In [24]: caller(1, 2.0, "string", {1:1}, [1,2,3])

In [25]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(float), Any(str), Any(dict), Any(tuple))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f607a20dd665> in <module>()
----> 1 caller.assert_called_with(Any(int), Any(float), Any(str), Any(dict), Any(tuple))

/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/mock.py in assert_called_with(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs)
    724         if self.call_args != (args, kwargs):
    725             msg = self._format_mock_failure_message(args, kwargs)
--> 726             raise AssertionError(msg)
    727 
    728 

AssertionError: Expected call: mock(0, 0.0, '', {}, ())
Actual call: mock(1, 2.0, 'string', {1: 1}, [1, 2, 3])
```

however this doesn't allow arguments that can be, for example, both an `int` or a `str`. Allowing multiple arguments to `Any` and using multiple-inheritance wont help. We can solve this using [`abc.ABCMeta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta)

```
def Any(*cls):
    class Any(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return isinstance(other, cls)
    for c in cls:
        Any.register(c)
    return Any()
```

Example:

```
In [41]: caller(1, "ciao")

In [42]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int, str), Any(int, str))

In [43]: caller("Hello, World!", 2)

In [44]: caller.assert_called_with(Any(int, str), Any(int, str))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I used the name `Any` for the function since it is "used as a class" in the code. Also `any` is a built-in...

Comment: I used a variation on this, but in newer versions of mock they use != as the comparison (at least for kwargs), so you need to override `def __neq__(self, other): return False` as well.

Comment: This is built into the framework now (sans type checking) as another answer brings out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27152023/452274

Comment: Mock provides a way. See answer from @k0nG

Comment: @Marcin No it doesn't. ANY  does not provide type checking.

Answer (score 401):

You can also use the `ANY` helper to always match arguments you don't know or aren't checking for.

More on the ANY helper: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any

So for instance you could match the argument 'session' to anything like so:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY
requests_arguments = {'slug': 'foo', 'session': ANY}
requests.post.assert_called_with(requests_arguments)
```

Comment: I use this solution too though but it does not give the type checking.

Comment: Side note: if you are using dict as input arguments, make sure include ** before your dict, in this case, requests.post.assert_called_with(**requests_arguments)

Answer (score 50):

```
@mock.patch.object(module, 'ClassName')
def test_something(self, mocked):
    do_some_thing()
    args, kwargs = mocked.call_args
    self.assertEqual(expected_url, kwargs.get('url'))
```

see: [calls-as-tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#calls-as-tuples)

Comment: Best answer to this question 

Answer (score 12):

**TLDR:**

```py
args, kwargs = requests.post.call_args_list[-1]
self.assertTrue('slug' in kwargs, '`slug` not passed to requests.post')
```

**In simple words, we get access to a tuple with all the positional arguments and a dictionary with all the named arguments that were passed to the function - so now you can check anything you want.**

---

I find this approach much cleaner than the other popular answers because: 
If there are too many parameters being passed and only one of them is to be checked, doing something like `{'slug': 'foo', 'field1': ANY, 'field2': ANY, 'field3': ANY, ' . . . }` can be clumsy.

Furthermore, if you wanted to check the datatype of a few fields:

```py
args, kwargs = requests.post.call_args_list[0]
self.assertTrue(isinstance(kwargs['data'], dict))
```

Also, if you're passing arguments (instead of keyword arguments), you can access them via `args` like this:

```py
self.assertEqual(
    len(args), 1,
    'post called with different number of arguments than expected'
)
```

Comment: This is a very clean methodology, as you do not need to know the quantity of arguments passed nor their names. For pytest users, it's as simple as `args, kwargs = requests.post.call_args_list[0]` then `assert 'foo' in kwargs` and `assert kwargs['foo'] == 'bar'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mock.call_args](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) to collect arguments your method was called with. If your mocked method has been called, it would return arguments your method was called with in the form of tuple of ordered arguments and key word arguments.

```
class A(object):
    def a_method(self, a, b,c=None):
        print("Method A Called")

def main_method():
    # Main method instantiates a class A and call its method
    a = A()
    a.a_method("vikalp", "veer",c= "Test")

# Test main method :  We patch instantiation of A.
with patch(__name__ + '.A') as m:
    ret = m.return_value
    ret.a_method = Mock()
    res = main_method()
    args, kwargs = ret.a_method.call_args
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

Above code will output odered arguments and keywords arguments as follows:

```
('vikalp', 'veer')
{'c': 'Test'}
```

You can assert on this like :

```
assert args[0] == "vikalp"
assert kwargs['c'] == "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one liner will assert that `requests_arguments` appears at least once in the list of positional arguments made to the calls of requests.post

`assert any(map(lambda args: requests_arguments in args[0], requests.post.call_args_list))`

Full working example:

```
import unittest.mock

post = unittest.mock.Mock()
post('foo')
post('bar')
assert any(map(lambda args: 'foo' in args[0], requests.post.call_args_list))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use : assert_any_call(args) 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_any_call

requests.post.assert_any_call(requests_arguments)